EKF slam with Error State parametrization
When using error state EKF formulation I'm a bit confused on how the measurement step works.
Intuitively state injection shouldn't alter feature point locations or probability distribution of them but I haven't seen an error state implementation.
Does it turn into a simple application of the chain rule?
